# How to validate date range?

Tags: jquery

How to validate date range?

I have the following code that validates a date range, where the end date is not allowed to be smaller than the start date.
However, there seems to be some flaw in the code that still allows the wrong date range.

```
function ValidateDates() {
            var data1 = $("#<%=txtDtSt.ClientID%>").val();
            var data2 = $("#<%=txtDtEnd.ClientID%>").val();

            var dateStart = ConvertForDate(data1);
            var dateEnd = ConvertForDate(data2);


            if (dateEnd < dateStart ) {
                criarDivAlert("Alert", "Range Incorret.");
                exibirAlerta(false);
                $("#<%=txtDtEnd.ClientID %>").val('');
               $("#<%=txtDtEnd.ClientID%>").focus();

            }
        }
        function ConvertForDate(data) {
            var dataArray = data.split('/');
            var newDate = new Date(dataArray[2], dataArray[1], dataArray[0]);

            return newDate;
        }
```

> Note that I still created a function to convert a text into a date to validate the values ​​correctly.

Test:

**Starting date: 02/01/2018
End Date: 31/01/2018**

You should enter the IF and warn that the date range is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code

```
function ValidateDates() {
        var data1 = $("#<%=txtDtSt.ClientID%>").val();
        var data2 = $("#<%=txtDtEnd.ClientID%>").val();

        var dateStart = ConvertForDate(data1);
        var dateEnd = ConvertForDate(data2);


        if (dateEnd < dateStart ) {
        alert("range is incorrect");
            //criarDivAlert("Alert", "Range Incorret.");
            //exibirAlerta(false);
            $("#<%=txtDtEnd.ClientID%>").val('');
           $("#<%=txtDtEnd.ClientID%>").focus();

        }
    }
    function ConvertForDate(data) {
        var dataArray = data.split('/');
        var newDate = new Date(dataArray[2],parseInt(dataArray[1]) - 1, dataArray[0]);

        return newDate;
    }
```

in javascript month starts from 0 so i did -1

```js
function ValidateDates() {
            var data1 = $("#txtDtSt").val();
            var data2 = $("#txtDtEnd").val();

            var dateStart = ConvertForDate(data1);
            var dateEnd = ConvertForDate(data2);


            if (dateEnd < dateStart ) {
   alert("range is incorrect");
                //criarDivAlert("Alert", "Range Incorret.");
                //exibirAlerta(false);
                $("#txtDtEnd").val('');
               $("#txtDtEnd").focus();

            }
            else alert("range is valid");
        }
        function ConvertForDate(data) {
            var dataArray = data.split('/');
            var newDate = new Date(dataArray[2],parseInt(dataArray[1]) - 1, dataArray[0]);

            return newDate;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtDtSt" />
<input type="text" id="txtDtEnd" />
<input type="button" value="Test" onclick="ValidateDates()"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below solution for checking Date Range :

```
function validation(date1,date2) {
    var v2 = document.getElementById('v2'),
      date = new Date(v2.value),
      dc1   = date.getTime(),
      dc2   = new Date(date1).getTime(),
      dc3   = new Date(date2).getTime();

   if (dc1 > dc2 || dc1 < dc3) {
       return true;
   }else{
       alert("date is not in valid range")
   }
}
```

Comment: But in this code you left the values ​​fixed. I need it to be dynamic and validate any date I type in the textbox

Comment: Simply you pass arguments in function 
function validation(date1 ,date2) {
// your code will be here
}

Comment: what is this document.getElementById('v2')? can you please help me to understand this?

Comment: If you are taking values from string then v2 will be id of that input tag